# Reload a RSSFeed on clicking a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'm new to iOS development and I've not got much experience with programming.  I either want to reload a `UITableView` from an RSS feed which I followed the following tutorial: [RSS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

I just can't seem to add a reload button to it as sometimes it fails to load first time and would like to add a button to the top bar the reload the data.

Like I said I've got next to nothing in experience with Objective-C but any help would be appreciated.

The following code is part of the code that refreshes the feed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.title = @"News";
    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://yourllanelli.org.uk/index.php?format=feed&type=atom",
        nil];    
    [self refresh];

    _reloadButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self action:@selector(reloadClick)]  autorelease];
}

-(void)reloadClick {    
    [UITableView refresh];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually getting the data from the RSS feed again when the `reloadClick` action is called.

You want to call your `refresh` method, and once your ASIHTTPRequests have all finished, you want to call `[UITableView reloadData]`

```
-(void)reloadClick
{    
    [self refresh];
}

- (void) requestDidFinish:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
     // you need to reload your UITableView once your ASIHTTPRequests finish.
     // since you are sending many requests to get the contents of different feeds, 
     // it would be better to call the following line only once, 
     // when all of the requests have finished
     [UITableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning:   ( Class method '+refresh' not found (return type defaults to 'id') )

Comment: there is a refresh routine. (I think it is a routine) `code`-   (void)refresh {
    
    for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [_queue addOperation:request];
    }
    
    } `code`

Comment: I got it to work now. Thanks Michael. I got another issue now though as I don't know how to clear the array to stop it from duplicating entries. Everytime it reloads it will add duplicates of all the entries. Do I just set the Array to nil?

Comment: Just do this: self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: I'm getting SIGABRT on the following bit of code:    `code`                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]`code`